# Laravel monthly count record

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel

I want to create monthly statistics using Chartjs by Laravel.

```
$monthly_uploaded_product = DB::table('author_product')
         ->select(DB::raw('count(id) as total'), DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))
         ->groupBy('month')
         ->get();
```

the result of query is:

```
[{"total":1,"month":10},{"total":17,"month":11}]
```

the output of code should be like this to be represented in Javascript (Chartjs):

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,17,0]
```

I have wrote code to generate the array, but error **Undefined offset: 1** :

```
$statistics_monthly_product = array();   
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    foreach ($monthly_uploaded_product as $key) {
        if ($statistics_monthly_product[$month] == $key->month){
            $statistics_monthly_product[$month] = $key->total;
        }else{
            $statistics_monthly_product[$month] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error message will also give you a filename and line number. Look there.

Comment: Try setting `$statistics_monthly_product` up as an array with 12 0s (`[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`), it might be that you're trying to access the first index of an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$year = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];//initialize all months to 0

foreach($monthly_uploaded_product as $key)
   $year[$key->month-1] = $key->total;//update each month with the total value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `$statistics_monthly_product = array();` creates a new array. Meaning that when you loop later on and try to do `$statistics_monthly_product[$month]` you are trying to access the index `$month` of an empty array. This will always give you the error of undefined index, since there is nothing in the array at all.

Perhaps you can initialize the array first with some default values:

`$statistics_monthly_product = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];`

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: He is wandering why he gets the undefined index, it is because the array he is accessing is a newly created array

Answer (score 0):

This code returns your expected array

```
$data = [["total" => 1,"month" => 10],["total" => 17,"month" => 11]]; 
$monthTotals = [];

foreach($data as $item){
    $monthTotals[$item["month"]] = $item["total"];
}

$chartJSCompat = [];
for($i = 0;$i < 12;$i++){
    if(isset($monthTotals[$i+1]))
        $chartJSCompat[$i] = $monthTotals[$i+1];
    else
        $chartJSCompat[$i] = 0;
}

var_dump($chartJSCompat);
```